I need to get these two lines in my variable into one single line. Power Automate variable

I need line 2 in the image to be combined with line 1. Below is what the full variable should look like.
CROWDSTRIKE FALCON EPP ENT FLEX BNDL T14.12M

I've tried wrapping the text and combining the text multiple ways but I cannot get the two lines into one.

How is the variable being generated right now?

Sorry not sure why the image didn't appear in my post. Below is how it is laid out. Two separate lines

CROWDSTRIKE PREVENT T14 1Y
T14.12M


you can put each string into a variable and then set the value to be:
%var1% %var2%


You can use the 'Replace Text' action.
so it looks like this:

Make sure to enable the 'Use regular expressions for find and replace'.
\r\n represents a carriage return and a new line in regular expressions.
Then in the 'Replace with' box, replace it with a an empty or blank character %''%
The result from the replace text action will show everything in one line.
As you can see my Description variable:

and the Replaced result

